# join multiple objects together depending on the distance

Tags: objects, scene, object-mode

Is there a way to select many objects and join only those that intersect or touch each other.
For example, I have a scene with houses and chimneys (seperated objects) and I want to batch join each house with its chimney.
I searched a lot for an addon or script but had no luck.
Thank you